# How to send text to an input element with type attribute as hidden using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, hidden

I'm new to python and selenium. I want to click on the `get_likes_button` and I need to send the value = 1803345990687013485 when doing that.

---

Here's the HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><span style="font-size: 14px;"> 
<i class="fa fa-heart" style="color: #F12938;"></i> 20 </span> 
<input type="hidden" value="1803345990687013485" name="id">
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" name="submit"
 id="get_likes_button"> Get Likes </button> </form></b>
```

---

Here's the code

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='id']").send_key('1803345990687013485')
driver.find_element_by_id('get_likes_button').submit()
```

I get the following message

> **Exception: Message: Element not visible.**

Comment: Where are you getting the exception? note that the first element has `type='hidden'` attribute. In addition, `get_likes_button` is `id`, not `name`.

Comment: Use findElementById() because get_likes_button is id.

Comment: I changed it to  findElementById() but I'm still getting the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Exception: Message: Element not visible.
```

...implies that the desired element is **not visible**.

The main issue is the `<input>` tag is having an attribute `type="hidden"`.

To send the *character sequence* **1803345990687013485** to the *input* field and invoke `click()` on the button you can use the following solution:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('id')[0].setAttribute('type','text')")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='id']").send_key('1803345990687013485')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary pull-right' and @id='get_likes_button']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet. Hope this will help you.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.navigate().to(URL);                    
JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecuter = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
javascriptExecuter.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('id')[0].value='452525252525';");
driver.findElement(By.id("get_likes_button")).submit();
```

Comment: The above code written in java. Use JavascriptExecutor  for updating hidden field value like above.

Answer (score 0):

For clicking on **Get Likes** button you can use this code :

```
get_likes = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "get_likes_button")))
```

After that if input type changed from `type='hidden'` , you can interact with input field as :

```
input_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "id")))
```

It's quite strange to see **HTML** like this :

```
<input name="id">
```

By the way, hope this will help.